# On attempting to sort smart table fires a new ajax call

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have an Angular.js smart table where the source of the data is an Ajax call using $resource. I've used st-pipe to specify the ajax function and I'm using st-safe-src.

On init the smart table completes the ajax request and loads the table.

So far so good but...

I have two issues...

1 - My default sort column is not being applied on initial load.

2 - I am finding that everytime I try and sort the data by clicking on a column header, smart tables is firing off a new Ajax call to retrieve the source data again.

I was hoping that smart tables would be able to sort client side and hence not have to do an ajax call for a sort. I believe that is what st-safe-src is for. Am I wrong?

Appreciate it someone could give me a hand.

Thanks

Here is my Controller...

```
eposWebAngularStrutsApp.controller('StoreHealthCheckController', ['StoreServerHealth', function (StoreServerHealth) {
    var ctrl = this;
    this.rowCollection = []; // base collection
    this.displayedCollection = [];  // displayed collection

    this.callServer = function callServer(tableState) { 
        ctrl.isLoading = true;
        StoreServerHealth.query(function(result) {          
            ctrl.rowCollection = result;
            ctrl.displayedCollection = [].concat(ctrl.rowCollection);
            ctrl.isLoading = false;
          })
          .error(function () {
              ctrl.errorMsg = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";

         });
    };  
}]);
```

Here is my template...

```
<div class="table-container" ng-controller="StoreHealthCheckController as mc">
<table st-table="mc.displayedCollection" st-safe-src="mc.rowCollection" st-pipe="mc.callServer" class="table table-striped ng-isolate-scope">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort-default="true" st-sort="locationId">Store</th>
        <th>Server</th>
        <th>Conn Status</th>
        <th>Last Updated</th>
        <th>MDI</th>
        <th>Last Synched (MDI)</th>
        <th>DSM</th>
        <th>Last Synched (DSM)</th>
        <th>Trading Status</th>
        <th>Build</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-show="mc.isLoading">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10" class="text-center">Loading ... </td>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>    
    <tbody ng-show="!mc.isLoading">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in mc.displayedCollection">
        <td>{{row.locationId}}</td>
        <td>{{row.clientId | clientIdToStoreServerType}}</td>
        <td>
            <img ng-src="img/{{row.status | statusToTrafficLightImage}}.png" alt="{{row.status}}"/>
        </td>
        <td>{{row.lastUpdateTime | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</td>
        <td><img ng-src="img/{{row.replicationStatus | statusToTrafficLightImage}}.png" alt="{{row.replicationStatus}}"/></td>
        <td>{{row.lastReplicationSyncTime | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</td>
        <td><img ng-src="img/{{row.dsmReplicationStatus | statusToTrafficLightImage}}.png" alt="{{row.dsmReplicationStatus}}"/></td>
        <td>{{row.dsmLastSynchTime | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss' }}</td>
        <td>{{row.storeTradingStatus | tradingStatusCodeToTradingStatus}}</td>
        <td>{{row.buildVersion}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>              
            </button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-server"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>               
            </button>                                   
        </td>           
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: No comments on this yet. As a sub question to this question, is Smart tables meant to make a new ajax request when the columns are sorted. I'm asking because in the smart tables code the pipe function is called at the end of the sort function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by taking out the st-pipe from my table definition and changing my controller as follows...

```
eposWebAngularStrutsApp.controller('StoreHealthCheckController', ['StoreServerHealth', function (StoreServerHealth) {

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.rows = [];
    ctrl.displayedRows = [];

    ctrl.isLoading = true;
    StoreServerHealth.query(function(result) {          
        console.log(result);
        ctrl.rows = result;
        ctrl.displayedRows = [].concat(ctrl.rows);
        ctrl.isLoading = false;
    });  


}]);
```

So concluding I don't know what the st-pipe is for.